# Unity Roll-a-Ball Tutorial Pickups not working in build but working in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, collision-detection

I’m on part 8.1 of the Unity Roll-a-ball tutorial.

When I run the build file it doesn’t pick up the pickups on the .exe file but when I run it in unity it does pick up the pickups.

The version of Unity I'm using is 2018.4.1f1

Roll-a-Ball Unity Video showing it working in Unity: https://youtu.be/jOgnqPJ-8Cc

Roll-a-Ball Build Video showing pickups not working in the .exe file: https://youtu.be/ZOhcSmLM9oQ

I'm trying to make it so it pickups up the pickups in the build like it does when I test it in Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the tags on the pickups prefab to untagged then changed the tags bag to pickup then saved the project then I removed the scene from the build settings then rebuild it with the open scene in the build settings and now it works fine